# Default repo location ignored in VS2022

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2022

VS2022 is ignoring my default repo path:

[image]

I have tried setting the correct path here:

[image]

(Yes, I clicked `OK` to save.)

The setting doesn't stick. After restarting VS and going back into that setting, I see that the setting has been blanked:

[image]

I tried restarting VS2022. It didn't help. I have re-entered the path, saved, restarted VS several times. It always gets blanked, and even before restarting, the default path isn't honored when I `Connect to a Project`.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: This was back when I used VS 2010. I remember I had troubles with solutions that existed in any drive except `C:`. I don't remember if that included drives assigned to a letter or UNC paths like `\\hostname\folder`.

Comment: Can you set the repo path to some place in the C drive?

Comment: I really need it on D - and it works fine in VS2019.

Comment: Does `D:\Dev\Git` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Turns out when your configured repo points to Git, you need to enter that default path from this angle:

[image]

Trying to do it from `Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Locations` or even `Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Git Global Settings` doesn't seem to stick when saved.

Answer (score 2):

> Default repo location ignored in VS2022

I have test it on my side, it works fine.

Please try to update your Visual Studio to the latest version, my current visual studio version is `Version 17.0.5`:

[image]

And if it still not work for you, please try to add the user name and e-mail as well.

Comment: I'm on latest as well: 17.0.5. I found the solution. Entering it now as an Answer...

Answer (score 0):

I just "thought" it wasn't honoring the default value, so providing the explanation for my scenario to anyone else who's wondering...

When I chose "Clone a repository..." from the menu then it properly showed the default value as expected. However, if I then clicked "Azure DevOps" under "Browse a repository", then when I selected a repository it would automatically fill in the old location. This is because I already had a cloned copy of the repository on my machine and it was assuming I might just want to open that existing copy instead of cloning a new one.

It's a bit of a confusing "feature" when you've explicitly said you want to clone a project and you're not expecting it to second guess your intentions.